# Screen Not Working and Lock Button Stuck

Tags: iphone, itunes

The screen has broken on my iPhone 4S and the On/Off button does not work. I had an idea that it might fix if I restart it (tell me if I'm wrong) but I can't. Is there a way that I can restart or even better update it from iTunes on the MacBook? I do know how to back it up.

Comment: You need the screen to login before you can back it up & you need the top button to be able to force it into DFU mode if it won't behave... so you're going to have to get one or the other fixed.

Comment: Probably I suggest you to go to the nearest machine store there.. They may help you with the button that gets stucked.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** Reboot iPhone by setting "Bold Text"

1. Open the Settings app and head to “General”
2. Go to “Accessibility” and locate “Bold Text”, flip that to the ON position
3. An alert will show up saying “Applying this setting with restart your iPhone” – so tap on “Continue” to immediately soft reboot device

**Method 2:** Restart the iPhone By Resetting Networking Settings

1. Head to Settings app and go to “General” and then to “Reset”
2. Locate “Reset Network Settings” and select it, then tap to confirm and reboot your phone.

If the issue is still not solved you'd better to call Apple or have someone check for you. Or you can check hcqs.cc for replacement parts and repair it yourself.